# ¿que significa esto: (struct sockaddr *)&client? || (client es un struct sockaddr_in)

Tags: c, socket

Estoy investigando sobre sockets en c y en las funciones `bin` y `connect` usa esto `(struct sockaddr *)&client` y no lo entiendo :'(

por lo que tengo entendido a una función le puedes pasar un tipo de datos o struct o int o char o el que quieres pero esto no lo había visto nunca. no entiendo porque pone el puntero los parentesis y el & alguien que sepa un poco más me podría explicar. A lo mejor me falta base para entenderlo pero estaría bien intentarlo y si me falta que me digais que tengo que aprender para que no me falte XD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### El problema de fondo

Los diseñadores de la API de sockets querían lograr estos dos objetivos:

- Soportar muchos tipos diferentes de "direcciones", de modo que los sockets no estuvieran ligados a una tecnología en particular (por ejemplo a TCP o UDP)
- Pero hacer una única función `bind()` que pudiera aceptar un socket y una dirección, para asignar esa dirección a ese socket.

Si te das cuenta, el problema aquí es que se quiere hacer una API "genérica", pero que después habrá que usar con protocolos "específicos".

Por ejemplo, el concepto de "IP y puerto" es específico del protocolo TCP o UDP. Los diseñadores de la API de sockets querían evitar que `bind()` recibiera específicamente una IP y puerto, pues eso no lo haría lo bastante genérico. Es posible imaginar otros esquemas de conexión y protocolos que no se basen en IPs ni puertos (por ejemplo quizás Bluetooth).

Así que el problema real es, si queremos que `bind()` reciba solo dos parámetros, el socket y la dirección ¿de qué tipo declarar la dirección?

¿Sabes algo de programación orientada a objetos? Si los diseñadores de la API de sockets hubieran usado un lenguaje que soportara OOP en vez de C, posiblemente habrían diseñado las cosas de otra forma. Por ejemplo, podrían haber declarado una clase abstracta llamada `GenericAddress`, y después derivar de ella clases concretas, como `TCPAdress`, `UDPAddress`, `BluetoothAddress`, etc.

Gracias al polimorfismo que permite OOP se podría entonces haber escrito una declaración de `bind()` cuyo segundo parámetro fuera declarado como `GenericAdress`, pero al momento de ser invocada pasarle en cambio una `TCPAdress`, por ejemplo.

### ¿Cómo lo resolvieron?

El C no tiene OOP ni polimorfismo. Por tanto el truco que usaron los diseñadores de la API fue declarar una estructura `sockaddr` que equivaldría a la clase `GenericAddress`. La estructura `sockaddr` simplemente tiene un campo llamado `sin_family` y ese campo está previsto para contener un número que sea diferente en cada "implementación concreta".

Después implementaron la estructura `sockaddr_in`, la cual sería un equivalente a `TCPAddress` o `UDPAddress` (estos dos casos son equivalentes a efectos de lo que deberían contener). En C no es posible declarar de ninguna forma que `sockaddr_in` es una "implementación particular" de `sockaddr`. Pero usando el primer campo `.sin_family` se pone ahí un código especial que identifica ese tipo como adecuado para direcciones IP/puerto.

Así, cuando vas a usar una estructura de ese tipo debes poner primero el valor especial `AF_FAMILY` en el campo `.sin_family`, y luego ya la IP y el puerto en los restantes campos.

El problema es que C exige que los tipos de los argumentos que pasas a una función coincidan con los tipos declarados en su cabecera. Por lo que tenemos aquí otro problema. Si se escribe un prototipo de `bind()` que espere como primer parámetro un socket y como segundo parámetro una `struct sockaddr` (la genérica), el compilador se quejará si luego en cambio le pasas una `struc sockaddr_in` (la particular con IP/Puerto).

El truco usado para "saltarse" esa restricción es pasar un puntero. Ya que un puntero es en el fondo una dirección de memoria, en cierta forma no es tan importante el tipo concreto al que apunta. Si se define `bind()` de modo que espere un puntero, se le podrá pasar **la dirección** de una `struct sockaddr_in` (eso es lo que consigues poniendo `&` delante del nombre de una variable, obtener su dirección). Entonces la función `bind()` puede estar programada de modo que acceda a la dirección a la que apunta el puntero, y lo que encontrará allí será el valor del primer campo `.sin_family`. Según el valor encontrado ya sabrá qué tipo de estructura se le ha pasado realmente, y por tanto podrá hacer un *casting* al tipo correcto para poder acceder al resto de elementos de esa estructura, si fuera necesario.

En realidad ni siquiera eso es necesario, porque `bind()` se limitará a copiar la estructura completa recibida, tal cual, a una zona de memoria de la que la implementación de TCP/IP del operativo la tomará. Es por eso que los datos dentro de esa estructura han de estar con la *endianity* de red (lo que obliga a usar `htons()` y similares).

Ya que el puntero indica dónde comienza la estructura a copiar, pero no dónde acaba, es necesario pasarle también a `bind()`, en un tercer parámetro, el número de bytes que ocupa esa estructura.

Todo esto nos lleva por fin a la siguiente situación:

- Prototipo de la función `bind()`:

  ```
  int bind(int sockfd, const struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t addrlen);
  ```

  El primer parámetro es el socket, que siempre será un `int`. El segundo es el puntero a la "estructura genérica" (que en cada llamada particular será una "estructura concreta"). El tercero es el tamaño en bytes de la estructura.
- Ejemplo de invocación de `bind()`:

  ```
  bind(s, &dir, sizeof(dir));
  ```

  Aquí `s` será un socket de tipo `int`, pero `dir` será una "estructura concreta", que depende de qué familia de direcciones estemos usando. Por ejemplo, una `struct sockaddr_in` si estamos usando la "familia de direcciones IPv4 más puerto".

Con este truco "casi hemos *engañado* al compilador". Pero no del todo. El compilador se quejará de que los tipos no coinciden exactamente en la llamada, ya que la función esperaba un `struct sockaddr *`, pero se le está pasando un `struct sockaddr_in *`. Pese a ese problema, el compilador **solo dará un warning** y compilará el programa de todas formas, y éste funcionará, porque a fin de cuentas lo que se pasa a una función es un puntero, sin que importe mucho si el tipo al que apunta es correcto o no (pues la función, como vimos, puede hacer internamente un casting al tipo que le interese en cada caso).

De todas formas, para eliminar ese *warning* y dejar al compilador "contento", podemos hacer un *casting* también en la llamada. El casting no es más que una forma de "forzar" a que el compilador vea una variable "provisionalmente" como si fuera de otro tipo. Consiste en poner delante de la variable y entre paréntesis el tipo que queremos forzar.

Así pues:

```
    bind(s, (struct sockaddr *) &dir, sizeof(dir));
```

Lo que aparece entre paréntesis delante de `&dir` es el *casting* y simplemente le dice al compilador "en este punto, considera que `&dir` es del tipo `struct sockaddr *`, confía en mí, sé lo que estoy haciendo aunque no es muy ortodoxo". Y por tanto ya compila sin *warnings*.

Comment: muchísimas gracias es decir me lo has dejado todo muy claro. Esque al ver los parentesis de (struct sockaddr*) y después el & pensaba que significaba y o algo así y no había pensado en la dirección de memoria y además también me has ayudado a entender mejor la librería winsocks2 que me estaba costando pero creo que con esto ya lo voy a conseguir

Answer (score 1):

Esa conversión es una mera convención.

`sockaddr` es un descriptor genérico, no está ligado a un tipo de socket en concreto.

En cambio `sockaddr_in` es una estructura específica para las conexiones bajo el protocolo IP.

En el descriptor le estás facilitando a las funciones `bind` o  `connect` información sobre qué tipo de estructura se va a encontrar realmente bajo ese puntero de tipo `sockaddr`:

```
int descriptor;
descriptor = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); // Conexión TCP
if (descriptor== -1)
    printf ("Error\n");

struct sockaddr_in socket;
socket.sin_family = AF_INET;
socket.sin_port = /* xxx */;
socket.sin_addr.s_addr =INADDR_ANY;

if (bind(descriptor, (struct sockaddr *)&socket, sizeof (socket)) == -1)
//       ~~~~~~~~~~
//       Aquí se le pasa información sobre el socket que recibe realmente
{
    printf ("Error\n");
}
```

Este mecanismo es un uso muy básico de polimorfismo

Comment: Yo diría que donde se le pasa de que tipo es realmente la dirección es en el primer campo de la estructura, el campo que contiene `AF_INET` en este caso. Por eso ese campo es el primero, porque la función confía en que sea eso precisamente lo que va a encontrar en la dirección que recibe como segundo argumento.

Comment: @abulafia AF_INET forma parte del descriptor, que es lo que defiendo en la respuesta. Bueno, realmente está en los dos campos....

Comment: En el descriptor lo que se guarda es `PF_INET`, que no es exactamente lo mismo, especialmente desde que tenemos IPv6. Quiero decir, al crear el socket especificas la _familia de protocolos_ (y eso queda guardado en el descriptor), pero después con `bind()`  le asignas una dirección, que pertenece a una _familia de direcciones_, que es lo que va en el campo `sin_family` de la estructura. Y no tiene por qué ser `AF_INET`, aún para un socket de protocolo `PF_INET`.